# Set boolean to true if it meets conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got 'task' model that contains boolean param named 'read' (task that has been read task.read = true, not read task.read = false) and int param 'assigned_to' (userid that is assigned to task).
I want 'read' to be true if userid that matches 'assigned_to' param entered the task.

```
task#show
        @task = Task.find(params[:id])
        @currentUser = User.find(current_user.id)
        currentUserId = @currentUser.id

        if @task.assign_to == currentUserId
            @taskIsAssignedToUser = true
        else
            @taskIsAssignedToUser = false
        end

        if @taskIsAssignedToUser && !@task.isRead?
            @task.set_read
        end

Task model:
  def set_read
    if (self.read == false)
      self.read = true
      self.save
    end
  end

 def isRead?
    if self.read?
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Actual result:
read isn't updated to true when userid that matches assigned_to enters the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to just this

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])

if @task.assigned_to == current_user.id
  @task.update(read: true)
end
```

And get rid of those model methods, they make no sense